# Why don't we use simple binary values to compress data?

Tags: data-compression

In Huffman's algorithm, we form a tree and than replace each character with the tree value of 1 and 0. Why don't we simply use the binary digits like $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=10$, $d=01$, $e=11$ and so on than replace them with the characters and when decompressing aplly the reverse and replace the binary digits with the alphabets?

Comment: There are definitely many possible codes.

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding? You have to read a bit if you want to understand. The first sentance says: *a Huffman code is an optimal prefix code*. What does it mean, and why is it important?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose we code, as you suggest, $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=10$, $d=01$, $e=11$, etc., and I send you the message $1001$. You can't tell if I said $10\,0\,1=cab$, $1\,0\,01=bad$. The point of the Huffman scheme is that it's a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), so it's uniquely decodable (and, further, you can always decode the start of the message based on the bits you've already seen, without having to look into the future).

Comment: The underlying concept is that of [prefix (free) codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code).

Comment: Huffman code for "abcd" is "000110111110" there is a chance of ambiguity as well isn't it?

Comment: There is no unique Huffman code for any given string. Huffman coding depends completely on the distribution of letters in the string you're encoding.